# How to determine an SSIS targetserverversion prior to adding it to an SSIS project

Tags: ssis

I opened up a Microsoft SSIS package file, MyPkg.dtsx,  in Notepad, The begining o fthe file is displayed below as XML

```xml
<DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
  DTS:refId="Package"
  DTS:CreationDate="5/11/2021 9:59:47 AM"
  DTS:CreationName="Microsoft.Package"
  DTS:CreatorComputerName="20JN-PF1HDB63"
  DTS:CreatorName="INTERNAL\C39293"
  DTS:DTSID="{2CAB3E50-7650-4A11-9AC5-8579A215ED38}"
  DTS:ExecutableType="Microsoft.Package"
  DTS:LastModifiedProductVersion="15.0.2000.166"
  DTS:LocaleID="1033"
  DTS:ObjectName="LOAD_STAGNG_IM_PA_PREM"
  DTS:PackageType="5"
  DTS:ProtectionLevel="0"
  DTS:VersionBuild="81"
  DTS:VersionGUID="{600D854C-25F0-4ED9-8207-3494AE3CB9FF}">
```

When I execute this statement against the database to see what version of SQL Server it was on,

```sql
select @@version
```

...this is the response:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3-GDR) (KB5021129) - 13.0.6430.49 (X64)   Jan 22 2023 17:38:22   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
```

The following is my understanding of how integer SQL Server version numbers relate to product names that include release year:

| Version | Release Date | Release name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11.0 |  | SQL Server 2012 |
| 12.0 | 5 June 2014 | SQL Server 2014 |
| 13.0 | 1 June 2016 | SQL Server 2016 |
| 14.0 | 29 September 2017 | SQL Server 2017 |
| 15.0 | 4 November 2019 | SQL Server 2019 |

Is the package compatible with running on the SQL server?  I added the package to two SSIS visual Studio projects, one with the Deployment Target version set to "SQL Server 2019" and the other was "SQL Server 2016". I didn't get a message that the above package would be upgraded nor did I get an error that the package was incompatible with the project when I added the package to each of the projects.

How do I determine if a package is compatible with my Visual Studio Integration product "targetServerversion" setting PRIOR to importing the package?

https://learn-attachment.microsoft.com/api/attachments/51807-targetserverversion.png?platform=QnA

Comment: In the XML snippet you provided, there is no explicit indication of the minimum required version. However, the LastModifiedProductVersion attribute indicates that the package was last modified using SQL Server 2019 (version 15.0.2000.166). This does not necessarily mean that the package is incompatible with earlier versions of SQL Server, but it suggests that the package may contain features or functionality that are specific to SQL Server 2019.

Comment: If you want to ensure compatibility with a specific version of SQL Server before importing the package, you can create a new SSIS project with the desired TargetServerVersion setting and then try to add the package to the project.

Comment: Visual Studio will display a dialog box asking if you want to upgrade the package to the current version. If the package is compatible with the selected "targetServerVersion," you should not see this upgrade prompt. Instead, the package will be added to the project without any compatibility warnings or errors.
If you do see the upgrade prompt, it indicates that the package may not be fully compatible with the selected "targetServerVersion." You can choose to proceed with the upgrade, but be aware that it might introduce changes to the package that could affect its behavior on the target serve